# How to load ViewModel/View in WPF under CaliburnMicro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I have a timer in my wpf application wich every 5 minutes ask a WCF service. If the service have message for my application, I get a list which contains text data and a specific code.

This code give an information about the view which must be loaded to print the data.

I have two ViewModel (the data source is the same for both): **One for a Ticker** > one view and **One for Popup** > two view

**Project files :**

1. View

   - Popup

     - PopHighView.xaml
     - PopMediumView.xaml
   - Ticker

     - TickerLayout.xaml
     - TickerNormal.xaml
2. ViewModel

   - PopViewModel
   - TickerViewModel
3. Models

   - AlertModel.cs
4. ViewParsers

   - AlertParser.cs

**Datasource :**

```
    public class AlertParser : IAlertParser{    
        AlertServiceClient service;    
        public List<AlertModel> TickerAlertData()    
        {        
            try        
            {           
                service = new AlertServiceClient();           
                List<AlertModel> items = (from item in service.GetActiveAlert()                 select new AlertModel        
                       {                  
                          Alertid= item.AlertId,                  
                          Alertstartdate = item.AlertStartDate,                  
                          Alerttitle = item.AlertTitle,                  
                          Alerttxt = item.AlertText               
                       }).ToList();            
                return items;        
            }        
            catch        
            {             
            return null;         
            }    
        }
   }
```

When my application is launched, there is no loaded view, only a icon in the systray(with wpf notifyicon).

My problem is, under theses circonstances, I don't understand how I could loaded a couple ViewModel/View, and pass the data to them, when my timer return a true from my service.

Many examples on the web have a mainview loaded, that's why I'm lost (like Conductor example on caliburn micro page).

Thanks for any help !

Edit :

Ok, My timer look like that :

```
if (service.IsAlertReady()=true)
{
    string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
    string myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
    service.IsAlertForMe(myIP);
    if(service.IsAlertForMe(myIP) == true)
    {
       ShellViewModel shell = new ShellViewModel();
       shell.ShowMediumPop();
    }
    else
    ...
```

**ShellViewModel**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    public void ShowMediumPop()
    {
        ActivateItem(new PopViewModel());
    }
}
```

**PopViewModel**

```
public class PopViewModel : screen
{
   protected override void OnActivate()
   {
      base.OnActivate();
   }
}
```

PopView.Medium

```
<UserControl x:Class="TerminalClientProto.View.PopView"
...
cal:View.Model="{binding}"
cal:View.Context="Medium"
>
```

I'm sorry but I don't understand how I could launch my view when my Ticker tick. I've read the documentation, but I need some hints to understand this mechanism.

Comment: When thinking about an event attempting to launch a view there are at least two ways to do this in WPF....    I'll post an answer to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

A program, any program, including the very program that contains the views you want to display can show a view in a number of ways.  Here's a few:

```
    var app = new App();        
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
```

Or you can start the view directly:

```
   var view = new MyView();
   view.Show(); 
   // or 
   view.ShowDialog();
```

If the view is a MainWindow, then you can create a ContentControl area within the view to inject the Usercontrol containing the sub-view of what you want displayed.  This still requires the MainWindow to be open...  So the examples above would also work when injecting UserControls into a MainWindow.  The act of injecting a User control is setting the ContentControl's Content to an instance of the User Control itself.  Eventhandlers can handle this scenario nicely...

```
public void NewUserControlInMainWindow(object sender, UserControl uc){
      //XCC = the Xaml content control in main window
      XCC.Content = uc;
}
```

I'm not really sure how Caliburn does view injection....

Comment: Caliburn seems to be, a little complex for me to understand at this moment. Mvvm light and Wpf notify Icon seems to be more simple to use together for my project.